# Create context for another site collection using NAPA

Tags: sharepoint-online, spcontext, napa

I am trying to access another site collection using NAPA. I found 2 ways, none of which seem to be working

[Office 365- Accessing lists refers wrong URL (URL/App name)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108573/office-365-accessing-lists-refers-wrong-url-url-app-name)

```
var context = new SP.AppContextSite(SP.ClientContext.get_current(), 'https://URL/sites/DevSite/');
```

The code stops at this line.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e52346e0-0592-451d-881d-2d49d237ffd5/create-site-with-jsom?forum=appsforsharepoint

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var appWebUrl1 = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
    var hostWebUrl1 = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")); var factory;
    this.context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl1);
    factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl1);
    this.context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    this.hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostWebUrl1);
```

`getQueryStringParameter` is underlined in red as "undefined"

Comment: Do you have a function with name `getQueryStringParameter`?

Comment: No, in the link provided it is also not defined, so I thought it was one of the default ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another question strikingly similar to this one open right now, but that one is primarily about AppWeb vs HostWeb differences -- so I'll tack an answer on here too:

***Important pre-requisite***: your app needs to ask for permission to read information from the host web:
In Napa, you'll find these settings by clicking the wrench icon (for project properties) on the left-hand navigation menu, then selecting "Permissions" -- make sure your app is at least asking for "Read" access on the "Web"

The MSDN example you've referenced should almost get you there, but you either need to add the `getQueryStringParameter` function from somewhere (you can probably find it in some examples at [OfficeDev/PnP](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/) -- or, a better option, is to use `SP.ScriptHelpers.getDocumentQueryPairs()` to retrieve the QueryString values from the current page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var qsVals = SP.ScriptHelpers.getDocumentQueryPairs();  
    var hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(qsVals.SPHostUrl);
    // note1
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    // note2
    var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostWebUrl);

    var hostWeb = appContextSite.get_web();
    // note3
    clientContext.load(hostWeb);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        // do stuff with the objects you loaded in the host web
        alert("Host web title: \n" + hostWeb.get_title());
    }, function(sender, args) {
        // something went wrong
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
});
```

Note 1: You can just use `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` here since you are working from the script that is on a page in the AppWeb.

Note 2: The `SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory` seems unnecessary in my experience - despite the fact that many of the examples use this pattern. Additional note here, `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` returns an instance of an already existing client context, so you do not use the `new` keyword. We're creating an `SP.AppContextSite` from nothing, so we do use the `new` keyword.

Note 3: You load the client objects with the App Web Context (the one we obtained with `get_current()` even though you navigate to the object from the `appContextSite` (the one we got from `new SP.AppContextSite()`.

Copying and pasting the entire code snippet into your browser dev tools (firebug, chrome js console, etc.) should give you an alert with the title of your host web.

The App model can take a while to get used to, take some time to check out blog posts out there and watch some videos on http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/ and http://dev.office.com/training

Comment: Thanks for a great answer and a lot of helpful hints. I eventually managed to achieve what I wanted using http://www.mavention.com/blog/sharePoint-app-reading-data-from-host-web. Your code stops for me at var qsVals = SP.ScriptHelpers.getDocumentQueryPairs(); If I use that line in a working code, it will be exactly where it will stop. Is it also a function I should write myself, or I am missing some reference?

Comment: No it is part of the SharePoint Javascript Object Model. If you're using the standard app template you should have a reference to it. Are you using SharePoint online?