# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when accessing list with JSOM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-hosted-app, authorization, jsom

I try to get items from a list with JSOM. But I get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException with error code 2147024891. If I navigate and authenticate to the site with a browser I am able to access the list without problems. So I think I have the correct permissions.

Here is my code:

```
function getClientContextForSiteURL() {
    var siteUrl = "/sites/mysite";

    return new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
}

function getList(context) {
    return context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Listname');
}

var clientContext = getClientContextForSiteURL();
var oList = getList(clientContext);

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>'" +
    "<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>");
sharePointCollectionListItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(sharePointCollectionListItems);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
              Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
              Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
```

Comment: Your code does work fine, I have seen it. Try using all these code in developer tools and then check the response text what you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running a SharePoint hosted app you can't just create a context for a different site and request data that way, it will run into [same-origin issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Luckily, the SharePoint App model has a couple of tools to solve this in the form of the [cross-domain library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn790708.aspx) (for using the REST API) or using an [`AppContextSite` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_AccessHostweb) (for the JSOM).

Here is an example from an answer I gave to another related question: [Create context for another site collection using NAPA](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126465/create-context-for-another-site-collection-using-napa/126479#126479)

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var qsVals = SP.ScriptHelpers.getDocumentQueryPairs();  
    var hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(qsVals.SPHostUrl);
    // note1
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    // note2
    var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostWebUrl);

    var hostWeb = appContextSite.get_web();
    // note3
    clientContext.load(hostWeb);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        // do stuff with the objects you loaded in the host web
        alert("Host web title: \n" + hostWeb.get_title());
    }, function(sender, args) {
        // something went wrong
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
});
```

Note 1: You can just use `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` here since you are working from the script that is on a page in the AppWeb.

Note 2: The `SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory` seems unnecessary in my experience - despite the fact that many of the examples use this pattern. Additional note here, `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` returns an instance of an already existing client context, so you do not use the `new` keyword. We're creating an `SP.AppContextSite` from nothing, so we do use the `new` keyword.

Note 3: You load the client objects with the App Web Context (the one we obtained with `get_current()` even though you navigate to the object from the `appContextSite` (the one we got from `new SP.AppContextSite()`.

Copying and pasting the entire code snippet into your browser dev tools (firebug, chrome js console, etc.) should give you an alert with the title of your host web.

---

**EDIT**:
Almost forgot, don't forget to [give your App permission to access the Host web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp142383.aspx) in the app manifest/app settings!

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to give the app the correct permissions in the app manifest.